localhost:11434/api/generate return error 404
I have an installation of Ollama that is working properly. When I send a request to it at   localhost:11434/api/generate
using curl, I get a proper response.
However, when I try to call it via haystack_integrations.components.generators.ollama.OllamaGenerator, I get error 404.
If I point the OllamaGenerator to localhost:11434,
I get some responses, but they are not in the proper format, so I think the function works properly.
What could be the reason that when I call the api/generate endpoint via OllamaGenerate, I get error 404?

In ollama-haystack==1.0.0, we adopted the Ollama python client. For consistency with the Ollama client approach, the URL to point at is http://localhost:11434.
When using this URL, everything should work properly.
I've just tried the example at https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack-core-integrations/blob/main/integrations/ollama/examples/generator_example.py and works as expected.
What problems are you encountering with the format of the responses?

Culprit seems to be upgrading to ollama-haystack==1.0.0
You might want to roll back the version to a previous one. I am using ollama-haystack==0.0.7 and it is able to generate the answers without throwing the said error for me.
